# Help with collections of categorized tags

Tags: discussion, tags, stackexchange

I've been working on categorizing tags in `CREATE TABLE` queries on this post, and I would like to request community help.

#### [Here is the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/330823/collections-of-categorized-tags)

The idea is to group tags in a way that's useful and can be copy-pasted as needed into other SEDE queries, depending on the set of tags you're interested in. I am by no means a pro on all this stuff, so if you have a few minutes to look over the results table and point out some improvements, that would be phenomenal.

Things to look for:

- Missing tags, in one category or another
- Misappropriated tags, i.e., a tag is in the wrong category, or should also be in another category
- "General" tags (look towards the bottom of the result set) that should be in a different list.

Please post an answer with one or many suggestions. I will take care of making the changes.

Comment: Why not just post the whole query as Community Wiki?

Comment: That is a good option, but I feel it needs clean-up. Anyone is free to fork it as they please, of course